# Criar caixa de procura no google docs

Tags: javascript, google, html-select

Boas,

tenho este código VBA e precisava de construir um Javascript para o Google Docs que faça a mesma coisa.
É possível converter o VBA em Javascript?

Obrigado.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim F1 As Worksheet
Dim intervalo As Range
Dim LastRow As Long
'Declara a Planilha pelo nome
Set F1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Folha1")
'Última Linha
LastRow = F1.Cells(F1.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

Set intervalo = F1.Range("A2:A" & LastRow)
'Caso não encontre TextBox2
If TextBox2 = "" Then
    MsgBox "Insira o nº da ficha a consultar."
'Se os campos de TextBox estiverem preenchidos
ElseIf TextBox2 > "" And TextBox1 > "" Then
'Realiza a procura
    With intervalo
        Set cellFound = .Find(TextBox1, LookIn:=xlValues)
        If Not cellFound Is Nothing Then
            FirstAddress = cellFound.Address
            Do
                'Realiza Ação após encontrar, faz offset de uma coluna para direita e segue o hyperlink. Então após encontrar na Coluna A, segue o hyperlink da coluna B.
                cellFound.Offset(0, 1).Hyperlinks(1).Follow
                Set cellFound = .FindNext(cellFound)
            Loop While Not cellFound Is Nothing And cellFound.Address <> FirstAddress
        End If
    End With
End If
TextBox2.SetFocus

End Sub

Private Sub TextBox1_Change()
    Dim intervalo As Range
    Dim texto As String
    Dim codigo As Integer
    Dim pesquisa
    Dim mensagem
    Dim F1 As Worksheet
    Set F1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Folha1")
    LastRow = F1.Cells(F1.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
   On Error Resume Next
    codigo = TextBox1.Text

    Set intervalo = F1.Range("A2:B" & LastRow)
    pesquisa = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(codigo, intervalo, 2, False)

    TextBox2.Text = pesquisa


End Sub

'Private Sub UserForm_Terminate()
'ActiveWorkbook.Close Savechanges:=False
'End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fiz uma solução em App Script que seria uma conversão do seu VBA. Espero que seja o que você precisa.

O link do arquivo funcionando é esse:
https://docs.google.com/document/d/1Kl7v3NnIBxOB_V6sIMiIyzFRN-CGsizq8_iZEtQVeBM/edit?usp=sharing

Foram criados dois arquivos no App Script, sendo eles:

Código.gs

```
function onOpen(e) {
   DocumentApp.getUi()
       .createMenu('Pesquisar')
       .addItem('Documentos', 'showSidebar')
       .addToUi();
}

function onInstall(e) {
  onOpen(e);
}

function showSidebar() {
  var ui = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('Sidebar')
      .setTitle('Pesquisar Documentos');
  DocumentApp.getUi().showSidebar(ui);
}

function BuscarCodigo(codigo) {

  if(codigo != null) {
    DocumentApp.getUi().alert(codigo);
  }

  var table = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getBody().getTables();

  var codigos = [];
  var links = [];
  var x = 1;
  while(x < table[0].getNumRows()) {
    codigos.push(table[0].getCell(x, 0).getText());
    links.push(table[0].getCell(x, 1).getText());
    x++;
  }

  var y = 0;
  var link = "";
  while(y < codigos.length) {
    if(codigo == codigos[y]) {
      DocumentApp.getUi().alert(links[y]);
      link = links[y];
      break;
    }
    y++;
  }

  AbrirLink(link);

}

function AbrirLink(link) {
  var ui = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(
  "<!DOCTYPE html> " +
  "<html> " +
  "<head> " +    
    "<script type='text/javascript'> " +    
    "function AbrirLink(){ " +
    " var popup = window.open('http://" + link + "'); " +
    " google.script.run.showSidebar(); " +     
    "} " +  
    "</script> " +  
  "</head> " +
  "<body onload='AbrirLink()'> " +
  "</body> " +  
  "</html> "  
  );
  DocumentApp.getUi().showSidebar(ui);
}
```

Sidebar.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  </head>
  <body onload="document.formulario.codigo.focus();">

    <style>
    .hidden {
      display: none;
    }
    </style>

    <br />

    <form role="form" id="formulario" name="formulario" align="center">

      <div class="form-group col-xs-12">
        <label class="sr-only" for="codigo">Código</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="codigo" id="codigo" placeholder="Insira o código do Documento">
      </div>

      <button class="btn btn-success hidden" align="center" id="pesquisaroculto">
        Pesquisar
      </button>

      <button class="btn btn-success" align="center" id="pesquisar">
        Pesquisar
      </button>

    </form>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> 
  </body>

  <script type="text/javascript">

    $(function() {
        $('#pesquisar').click(runPesquisa);
        $('#pesquisaroculto').click(runPesquisaOculto);
    });

    function runPesquisaOculto() {

      $("#pesquisaroculto").prop("disabled",true);
      $( "#pesquisar" ).removeClass("hidden");
      $("#pesquisar").prop("disabled",false);
      $( this ).addClass("hidden");

      var codigo = $('input[name=codigo]').val();

      google.script.run.BuscarCodigo(codigo);

    }

    function runPesquisa() {

      $("#pesquisar").prop("disabled",true);
      $( "#pesquisaroculto" ).removeClass("hidden");
      $("#pesquisaroculto").prop("disabled",false);
      $( this ).addClass("hidden");

      var codigo = $('input[name=codigo]').val();

      google.script.run.BuscarCodigo(codigo);

    }

  </script>

</html>
```

É somente a lógica sem validação de campos em branco que pode ser feita no html normalmente. Todos novos valores inseridos na tabela irão funcionar.

Não tem como fazer um campo de pesquisa dentro do Google Docs.

O que eu fiz foi um menu de Pesquisa de documentos no menu chamado "Pesquisar > Documentos" que abre um sidebar com um campo para digitar o código do documento e um botão para Pesquisar o documento.

Ao clicar nesse botão o link do documento pesquisado é aberto em uma nova guia.

Comment: Boas Filipe, antes de mais muito obrigado. Copiei o código para o meu drive e quando carrego no pesquisar no sidebar aparece uma mensagem de "a pagina pode estar temporariamente indisponível ou ter sido removida". Fiz alguma coisa de errado? Obrigado

Comment: O link do documento que eu compartilhei está funcionando? Deixei ele publico para qualquer pessoa ter acesso ao código e ao exemplo funcionando. Para copiar o código seria bom criar uma cópia do documento e do código e executar o método showSidebar dentro do app script para pegar as permissões necessárias.

Comment: Fiz um teste agora. Se você fizer a cópia do documento o código em app script vai ser copiado também. Depois de fazer a cópia entre no Editor de scripts pelo caminho: Ferramentas > Editor de scripts e execute o método showSidebar. Vai aparecer uma tela falando que a página não é segura. Isso acontece porque foi um método feito por um usuário e não foi publicado nos códigos do google. Pode continuar e aceitar as permissões para funcionar. Qualquer dúvida só me contatar.

Comment: Boas Filipe, agradeço a sua ajuda e quero perguntar se é possível quando procuramos pelo código quando aparece o link se dá para clicar logo no link e abrir a página?

Comment: Seu pop-up deve estar bloqueado por questão de segurança do navegador. Permita os pop-up para esse site e realize o teste que deverá funcionar.

Comment: Os alertas que eu mostrei são somente para mostrar que os valores estão sendo pegados. Pode comentar esses códigos que o site irá abrir do mesmo jeito.